Wiremock customization of attributes
I have an API A which is used by UI to display some data. There are some internal APIs called and the data is collected and returned by API A. So, the flow is something like this:
API A ---> API B
On a happy path, API B returns all the attributes, but on a bad day, same API B may excludes some of the attributes which in turn changes the response of API A. The processing of API A tackles the missing attributes and performs necessary steps.
We are planning to use wiremock to test this. The problem is that we are ending with too many wiremock stubs to tackle missing attribute scenario. If we were to do this programmatically, it would be lot easier, since we could have just one input and can change the response depending on the test case.
Is there a way do the same via file stubbing ?, i.e. we have one stub mapping but the mock response is edited in the setup of the test case ?

Can you provide a minimum reproducible example of the issue? How different is each request? Which API are you mocking?

Yes you can programmatically cover multiple test cases/missing attributes in your response file. In the stub you just need to add response-template transformer. This is how mapping stub would look like:
{
        "priority": 1,
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "urlPathPattern": "/program"
        },
        "response": {
            "status": 200,
            "bodyFileName": "upsertGeneral.xml",
            "transformers": [
                "response-template"
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "text/xml"
            }
        }
    }

This is how response file upsertGeneral.xml would look like. Basically you just assign "variables" and provide path to them. If they are present, you define what needs to be returned or else if they are not present:
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Body>
    <upsertResponse>
  {{#assign 'upsert'}}{{xPath request.body '/Envelope/Body/upsert'}}{{/assign}}
  {{#if upsert}}
     <result>
           {{#assign 'username'}}{{xPath request.body '/Envelope/Body/upsert/username/text()'}}{{/assign}}
           {{#if username}}
              <created>UsernamePresent</created>
            <id>{{xPath request.body '/Envelope/Body/upsert/username/text()'}}</id>
           {{else}}
              <created>UsernameNotPresent</created>
            <id>generating random username: {{randomValue length=18 type='ALPHANUMERIC'}}</id>
           {{/if}} 
  {{/if}}
        <success>true</success>
        </result>
    </upsertResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Request example:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <upsert>
        <username>testusername</username>
    </upsert>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response:
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Body>
    <upsertResponse>
        <result>
            <created>UsernamePresent</created>
            <id>testusername</id>
            <success>true</success>
        </result>
    </upsertResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Request example with missing username:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <upsert>
        <username></username>
    </upsert>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Result else path:
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Body>
    <upsertResponse>
        <result>
            <created>UsernameNotPresent</created>
            <id>generating random username: rtqorbniv0hz0d1j5o</id>
            <success>true</success>
        </result>
    </upsertResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Hope this helps :)
